# In Rails how would one generate a unique serial number for a new instance of a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, auto-increment, ruby-on-rails-3

In Rails, I'm looking for a way to generate an auto-incrementing serial number for internal record keeping for new instances of a model. I would like to avoid creating database specific code and rather have a solution that will work regardless of the database. My current idea is to wait until the model is saved and then grab the ID of the saved model and use that as a suffix of the serial number, but then I would have to save each record twice on creation.

Any ideas?

Thanks for looking!

Comment: One reason I would recommend against this is that you will probably end up running multiple rails apps and keeping a single number unique across all of your applications and multiple physical boxes will be very difficult. There is probably a way to accomplish what you want via the database. Can you shed any more light on the serial number format and constraints?

Comment: Thanks for your response. The serial number will be a string in the format PLN-xxxxxx. I'm thinking of just starting at "PLN-100000" and incrementing from there.

Comment: So all records will have PLN- infront of their serial numbers?

Comment: Correct, its just a prefix that differentiates between different models.

Comment: Why not just use the id and add the PLN- prefix in the code when you display it? And why do you want to avoid using the database?

Comment: I think I phrased that poorly. What I meant was I wanted a solution that didn't rely on coding for a particular database. I'll update my question. I would like to include the prefix so users can do a search by typing in a number with the prefix and not get duplicate entries from different models.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would recommend constructing the serial model in the model instead. This will give you more flexibility to adjust the serial number format later, and it will keep the unique auto-increment in the database instead. Use a regular auto-increment integer primary key and then create the serial number like this:

```
class Product
  def serial_number
    "PLN-%.6d" % id
  end
end
```

So if you have a product with id = 567 for example, you'll have a serial number like this:

```
Product.find(567).serial_number
=> PLN-000567
```