# In Rails how can I prefix id with letter "N" and save as item number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string-concatenation

I need to be able to create an item number based on the product id, prefixed by the letter "N".  I have seen these two questions about [prefixing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569391/in-rails-how-would-one-generate-a-unique-serial-number-for-a-new-instance-of-a-m) and using [callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793045/ruby-on-rails-concatenate-strings-on-save-to-database-upon-user-clicking-creat).

I am new to Ruby on Rails and programming in general.  How can I combine both questions so that after_save my item number field will be updated with the newly concatenated K + id?

I am using Ruby 2.3 and Rails 4.2.5.

**Update - Final Solution**
Thanks to @born4new, the final code I used in my model to get this to work is as follows.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :create_item_number

  private
    # Concatenate ID with prefix N to create item number
    def create_item_number
      update_column(:item_number, self.item_number = "N#{id}")
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a simple string concatenation like so:

```
after_save :prefix_number

[...]

private

def prefix_number
  self.number = "N#{id}"
end
```

Comment: Thanks alot @born4new, I will update the question with the final code I used for the model.